# Expected Values of Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose I have a function $L(c)$ , where $c$ is a continuous random variable. Let

$L(c)=c+log(E[\theta])$

where $\theta$ is a continuous random variable and $E$ representing the corresponding expected value. My question is , is it fair to state that $L(c)$ itself is an expected value as it is expressed in terms of an $E(\cdot)$.

1. If this is true could you please explain why?
2. If this is not true could you please explain why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here $L(c)$ is a random variable, hence not an expectation. You can at most see $L(c)$ as a *conditional* expectation wrt a random variable. This is true for every random variable: $X=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid X]$.

Answer (score 1):

No. First of all, we generally denote random variables as capital letters $X$ and constants as lower case $x$ to avoid confusion.

$E\theta$ is just a constant. It's no longer random after taking expected value. So what this function $L(C)$ is doing is simply adding a constant to the random variable.

$L(C)$ is therefore still a random variable, except its now of the form

$C + a$

Where $a=\log E\theta$.

To refer to something as an "expected value" it needs to be of the form $E f(X)$ for some r.v. $X$ and function $f$. Since $L(C)$ is still a random variable (not constant) it is not an expected value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It clear everything up. Regarding the comment by drhab, are you aware what the reference/link to conditional expectation is?

Comment: when you take expectation conditioned on a random variable, the resulting expectation is random. However this is different from the kind of expectation you are talking about. I wouldn't worry to much about it if you have not come across it yet

Answer (score 0):

It is not an expected value. Remember that a random variable is a function that maps **sets** to **values**. However, expectation is a function that maps **functions** to **values**. In your case. $L(c)$ still maps **sets** to **values** and the expectation has already resolved to a number.

Comment: rv maps sets to values? But a random variable is a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ where $\Omega$ is a set...The elements of $\Omega$ are not necessarily sets (provided we are not busy with set-theory here, where everything is a set).